# Is there a way to facet a line graph but add a constant line in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I am making a line graph using ggplot of some data that I have were I am sizing objects based on treatment groups into bins and looking at the percentage in each size bin by group.

My goal is to facet the data but have the control line as a graph but also added to the other groups when they facet.

I have the graph working were I get all of my groups one of which is my control and I can facet it. I just would to keep the control line on the subsequent graphs but slightly grayed out. I am not sure how to add that.

```
graph <- ggplot(data=my_data, aes(x=bins, y=p_per_bin, group = group, 
                                        color = group, linetype = group, shape = group))+
     stat_summary(fun = "mean", geom = "line", lwd = rel(1))+
     stat_summary(fun = mean,
                  geom = "pointrange",
                  fun.max = function(x) mean(x) + sd(x) / sqrt(length(x)),
                  fun.min = function(x) mean(x) - sd(x) / sqrt(length(x)))+
     stat_summary(fun = "mean", geom = "point", size = rel(2), fill = "white", stroke = rel(1.1))
   
   graph + facet_wrap(~group)
```

Here is a portion of my data as a sample. Group "a" is the control.

```
sample <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6,7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9)
group <- c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b",
           "b","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c")
bins <-c("0-20","20-40","40-60","0-20","20-40","40-60","0-20","20-40","40-60","0-20","20-40","40-60", "0-20","20-40","40-60", "0-20","20-40","40-60", "0-20","20-40","40-60", "0-20","20-40","40-60", "0-20","20-40","40-60")
p_per_bin <- c(0,37.7192982,21.0526316,0,36.744186,23.7209302,0,36.2126246,31.5614618,
0,31.25,27.0833333,0,41.2280702,28.5087719,0,39.6078431,31.372549,0,43.7262357,
20.1520913,0,35.4716981,21.1320755,0,38.5350318, 29.9363057)
my_data <- cbind(sample,group,bins,p_per_bin)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to add your reference group via an additional `stat_summary` for which you only use the data on the reference group. To get this layer displayed on each facet it's important to drop the `group` column after filtering.

For the example code I have chosen group "a" as the reference group:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ggplot(data = my_data, aes(
  x = bins, y = p_per_bin, group = group,
  color = group, linetype = group, shape = group
)) +
  #### Add line for reference group
  stat_summary(fun = "mean", geom = "line", lwd = rel(.5), 
               data = ~filter(.x, group == "a") |> select(-group), 
               color = "grey45", linetype = "solid") +
  ####
  stat_summary(fun = "mean", geom = "line", lwd = rel(1)) +
  stat_summary(
    fun = mean,
    geom = "pointrange",
    fun.max = function(x) mean(x) + sd(x) / sqrt(length(x)),
    fun.min = function(x) mean(x) - sd(x) / sqrt(length(x))
  ) +
  stat_summary(fun = "mean", geom = "point", size = rel(2), fill = "white", stroke = rel(1.1)) +
  facet_wrap(~group)
```

[image]

Comment: I try running this code and I get an error:  in `+.gg`:
! Cannot add ggproto objects together. Did you forget to add this object to a ggplot object?

Comment: Hm. I just checked again and works fine . Perhaps an issue with native pipe `|>` which require R > 4.1.0. If your are running an older version you have to replace it by the magrittr `%>%`

Comment: Thank you, I changed it to %>% and it works on the sample data now. However, when I run it on the full data set it does not add the line and outputs: Adding missing grouping variables: `group`

Comment: Hm. As you get the famous warning about the missing group aes a fix would be to explicitly add it, i.e. try with `stat_summary(aes(group = 1), fun = "mean", geom = "line", lwd = rel(.5), data = ~filter(.x, group == "a") %>% select(-group), color = "grey45", linetype = "solid")`